# Login as other user (masquerade)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, doorkeeper

I've build an that has a RubyOnRail backend(Restful Oauth API). I'm using door keeper for the oauth. I'd like to be able to login as another user with a sort of "Super Password".

Some really bad sudo code for what i'm trying to do

```
user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first
if(user.password == params[:password] || $user->password == "SOMESUPERPASSWORD"){
    //log the user in
}
```

Where would I put this code? Can i have a custom login function for devise?

Maybe the super password approach is incorrect. What do you guys thing?

Comment: Try the [switch_user](https://github.com/flyerhzm/switch_user) gem. Make sure you don't deploy it to production unless you want all your users to be able to log in as each other!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a custom authorization method with doorkeeper. I adapted my working code to your case and I think this should work for any custom validation method using doorkeeper.

In doorkeeper.rb

```
resource_owner_authenticator do
current_user ||= User.find_by_session_key(session[:session_key]) if session[:session_key].present?
session[:user_return_to] = request.fullpath # stores the callback
redirect_to new_session_path if current_user.nil? 
current_user #because resource owner block has to return a user
end
```

in sessions controller, I have no logic for new.  It just renders a form asking for username and password.  Then in sessions controller create:

```
def create
# put your custom logic here
user = User.where(username: params[:username]).first
if (user.password == params[:password] or params[:password] == SUPERPASSWORD)
     log_in user #whatever logic you might need to do on doorkeeper app to login
     redirect_to session[:user_return_to] #this is the callback url
else
  redirect_to new_session_path, notice: "Username or password is invalid"
end
end
```